# SharedPreferences & variables swap

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Basically I'm getting an int and a String everyday, that I save into SharedPreferences

What I want is those variables to change their values on each new day, passing from CurrentDay > Day+1 > Day+2 > Day+3 etc... and I need to save them.

For instance, let's say today's color is RED

```
// Not actual coding
DAY            -         STATE
Today : Red > 0 > 0 > 0
Tomorrow : NewColor1 > Red > 0 > 0
2 days later : NewColor2 > NewColor1 > Red > 0
3 days later : NewColor3 > NewColor2 > NewColor1 > Red
4 days later : NewColor4 > NewColor3 > NewColor2 > NewColor1 (Red is gone, overwritten by NewColor1)
```

For example:

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences;

private String mTextA, mTextB, mTextC;
private int mColor1, mColor2, mColor3;

private String mCurrentText, mYesterdayText, mTwoDaysAgoText, mThreeDaysAgoText;
private int mCurrentColor, mYesterdayColor, mTwoDaysAgoColor, mThreeDaysAgoColor;

//String keys for SharedPreferences storage (int values)
private static final String CURRENT_COLOR = "CURRENT_COLOR";
private static final String YESTERDAY_COLOR = "YESTERDAY_COLOR";
private static final String TWO_DAYS_AGO__COLOR = "TWO_DAYS_AGO_COLOR";
private static final String THREE_DAYS_AGO_COLOR = "THREE_DAYS_AGO_COLOR";

//String keys for SharedPreferences storage (String values)
private static final String CURRENT_TEXT = "CURRENT_TEXT";
private static final String YESTERDAY_TEXT = "YESTERDAY_TEXT";
private static final String TWO_DAYS_AGO_TEXT = "TWO_DAYS_AGO_TEXT";
private static final String THREE_DAYS_AGO_TEXT = "THREE_DAYS_AGO_TEXT";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
mPreferences.edit().putInt(CURRENT_COLOR, mCurrentColor).apply();
mPreferences.edit().putInt(CURRENT_TEXT, mCurrentText).apply();

// This is where I'm having troubles with the logic 

     if (newday == true) {

            // Day 3
            mThreeDaysAgoColor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(TWO_DAYS_AGO_COLOR, 0);
            mThreeDaysAgoText = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(TWO_DAYS_AGO_TEXT, null);

            // Day 2
            mTwoDaysAgoColor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(YESTERDAY_COLOR, 0);
            mTwoDaysAgoText = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(YESTERDAY_TEXT, null);

            // Yesterday
            mCurrentColor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(CURRENT_COLOR, 0);
            mCurrentText = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(CURRENT_TEXT, null);


            mPreferences.edit().putInt(YESTERDAY_COLOR, mYesterdayColor).apply();
            mPreferences.edit().putInt(TWO_DAYS_AGO_COLOR, m2DaysAgoColor).apply();
            mPreferences.edit().putInt(THREE_DAYS_AGO_COLOR, m3DaysAgoColor).apply();


            mPreferences.edit().putString(YESTERDAY_TEXT, mYesterdayText).apply();
            mPreferences.edit().putString(TWO_DAYS_AGO_TEXT, m2DaysAgoText).apply();
            mPreferences.edit().putString(THREE_DAYS_AGO_TEXT, m3DaysAgoText).apply();
```

To clarify:

- mCurrentText can be mTextA, mTextB or mTextC
- mCurrentColor can be mColor1, mColor2, or mColor3

Whenever my app detects a new day >

- mCurrentText is saved as mYesterdayText
- mCurrentColor is saved as mYesterdayColor

then it becomes Day+2, Day+3 etc, everything moves from one row, until Day+4 when Day+3 gets overwritten.

As a final result, I want to be able to read & save the values of mYesterdayText/mYesterdayColor, mTwoDaysAgoText/mTwoDaysAgoColor & mThreeDaysAgoText/mThreeDaysAgoColor for each new day.

I don't know if I'm going the wrong way or not. Please I need some help, I'm a newbie :(

Comment: what doo you mean by " move by one " ?

Comment: For instance, let's say that my mCurrentText is "SHEEP", the next day mYesterdayText takes the value of "SHEEP", then one more day after mTwoDaysAgoText takes the value of "SHEEP", and one more day and mThreeDaysAgoText takes the value of "SHEEP" etc. Then, as I don't need to display after 3 days ago, "SHEEP" gets overwritten by the current mTwoDaysAgoText value etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get your problem, you want to shift the values of colors:

```
Today's launch : Red > 0 > 0 > 0
Tomorrow's launch : NewColor1 > Red > 0 > 0
2 days later's launch : NewColor2 > NewColor1 > Red > 0
3 days later's launch : NewColor3 > NewColor2 > NewColor1 > Red
4 days later's launch : NewColor4 > NewColor3 > NewColor2 > NewColor1 (Red is gone, overwritten by NewColor1)
```

For this, you don't need to change the mCurrentText at all.
Have the following variables in shared pref (explaining just for TEXT):

```
CURRENT_TEXT, YESTERDAY_TEXT, TWO_DAYS_AGO_TEXT, THREE_DAYS_AGO_TEXT
```

initialize each with empty or default values you want.

Now whenever theres a new day, you just need to overwite the values as follows:

```
putInt(THREE_DAYS_AGO_TEXT, {get value from shared pref of TWO_DAYS_AGO_TEXT})
putInt(TWO_DAYS_AGO_TEXT, {get value from shared pref of YESTERDAY_TEXT})
putInt(YESTERDAY_TEXT, {get value from shared pref of CURRENT_TEXT})
putInt(CURRENT_TEXT, {get value of new text for today})
```

...and you will have the desired output.

Comment: Yeah, you got my idea. But isn't it the same thing I'm already doing? Does the order of the saving/loading matter since JAVA is sequential? Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Thank you sir, you helped me a lot. It's now working as intended :)

Comment: @RobertDisto Glad that it worked, and yes order of saving and loading does matter! :)